# Can not upload file from React to Express with Multer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

When I try the Post request in postman I have no issues in sending the file to the destination, so there appears to be no issue on the backend. But on the front end something is going wrong and I cannot figure out what the issue is , when I try to use react the **`MulterError: Unexpected field`** error pops up. Please can some one show me where I am going wrong.

React code

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import Message from './Message';
import Progress from './Progress';
import axios from 'axios';

const FileUpload = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState('Choose File');
  const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({});
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0);

  const onChange = e => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
          setUploadPercentage(
            parseInt(
              Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
            )
          );

          // Clear percentage
          setTimeout(() => setUploadPercentage(0), 10000);
        }
      });

      const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;

      setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });

      setMessage('File Uploaded');
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
        setMessage('There was a problem with the server');
      } else {
        setMessage(err.response.data.msg);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {message ? <Message msg={message} /> : null}
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className='custom-file mb-4'>
          <input
            type='file'
            className='custom-file-input'
            name="image"
            id='customFile'
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <label className='custom-file-label' htmlFor='customFile'>
            {filename}
          </label>
        </div>

        <Progress percentage={uploadPercentage} />

        <input
          type='submit'
          value='Upload'
          className='btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4'
        />
      </form>
      {uploadedFile ? (
        <div className='row mt-5'>
          <div className='col-md-6 m-auto'>
            <h3 className='text-center'>{uploadedFile.fileName}</h3>
            <img style={{ width: '100%' }} src={uploadedFile.filePath} alt='' />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;
```

express code

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, res, cb){
      cb(null, `${__dirname}/client/public/uploads/`)
  },
  filename: function(req, files, cb){
      cb(null, files.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ path.extname(files.originalname))
  }

})



const upload = multer ({storage, limits: {fieldSize: 10000000}, fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){checkFileType(file, cb)}}).single('image')


function checkFileType(file, cb){

  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;

  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase())

  const mimetype =filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if(mimetype && extname){
      return cb(null, true)
  } else {
      cb('Error: image only')
  }
}


app.post('/upload', upload, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file)
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Server Started...'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `.single('image')`, you are expecting the file to be passed in the form field `'image'`

But you are using `formData.append('file', file)`, which attaches the file at the field `'file'`

You have to change the field names to be consistent, either `'image'` or `'file'`